# How to use camelize function for CAPITAL case payload/string

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Sample Request:

```
{
    "message": "HELLO world!"
}
```

DataWeave script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
camelize(payload.message)
```

Output Received:

```
"hELLO world!"
```

Expected Output:

```
"hello world!"
```

Comment: Hi @Rathna. It seems that you didn't read the documentation of camelize(). It doesn't do what you expect. See the solution below.

Answer (score 3):

as per your requirement you need all letters of a given string in lowercase, for that use "lower()" funciton that returns the provided string in lowercase characters as in below code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
lower(payload.message)
```

the output will be as you are expecting.

This is the screen shot for input, dw script and ouput

[image]

below are the official Mulesoft documents link

1. Camelize:  https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.2/dw-strings-functions-camelize
2. Lower : https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-lower